# Windows 10 Redstone 4 Media Feature Pack missing?

Tags: windows-10

Recently, I downloaded Windows 10 Redstone 4 and noticed that my version was missing the Media Feature Pack. So I tried to download it from http://microsoft.com/ and faced a new problem -- that version did not match with my OS version. So I searched for the latest version but I didn't find it, either on the Microsoft website nor on any website.

So what should I do and how can I get the Media Feature Pack that matches with my OS?

Answer (score 2):

> Recently I downloaded windows 10 Redstone 4, and I noticed that my
>   version Was missing the media feature pack

Windows 10 Redstone 4 (also known as Windows 10 Version 1803) was released on April 30th, 2018.

You can download the Media Feature Pack [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack)

Comment: Since this question was submitted before April 30th, 2018, there is a chance you are running build 17133 instead of 17134, if that is the case you need to be sure the current RS4 17134 build before you install the Media Feature Pack.

Comment: I went ahead and updated this question, since the Media Feature Pack actually is available now , I didn't see the usefulness of an answer that said it wasn't released.